# Python requests: Method not allowed error

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to access [this](https://www.propertyshark.com/mason/Property/53047525/1302-Richland-Ave-Santa-Ana-CA-92703/) URL  by using `requests.get()` but it gives *405*. No such issue when accessing via browser.

Comment: inspect your browser's header data and set your request to send the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added the proper headers required, try this

```
import requests

headers = {
                "Host": "www.propertyshark.com",
                "Connection": "keep-alive",
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36",
                "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
                "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
                "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
                "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
}

url = "https://www.propertyshark.com/mason/Property/53047525/1302-Richland-Ave-Santa-Ana-CA-92703/"

req = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(req.status_code)
```

Comment: @Volatil3 why randomly? what does it show otherwise?

Comment: 405 appears then.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess,probably because you are trying to access the page directly.

Can you try adding a referral url 
Where my_referer is the url of the website home page

requests.get(url, headers={'referer': my_referer})